# What does 'grab some crap' mean?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

> X: Cattle mutilations, small town, couple hours out. Pays one-fifty
> (150)
>
> Y: Cattle mutilations? Well, that, for sure, that's 200 bucks.
>
> ....
>
> Y: I don't want to talk to you. Send me the details. I'm gonna run
> home and **grab some [crap](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/crap)**.

-- *The Unholy (2021)*

That line is spoken by the man, he's a journalist that's being phoned by his friend (**X**). Probably talking about the job or offering something. I don't really get it. The next scene, he's talking to another guy near the church and I don't think if I continue the details it will be connected/linked to the conversation above.

Anyway, I want to know what does he mean when he says that? Is he going to grab his camera to record something (remember that he's a journalist) or money or what?

Comment: To the downvoter, do you have something to say?

Comment: The scatological allusion here is probably heavily influenced by the almost infinitely more common usage *I gotta run home and **grab my shit*** (fetch my contextually relevant belongings).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, "crap" is slang and means "stuff" or "things". So the man is saying, "I'm going to run home and grab some things."